# Using Bitbucket in Eclipse che in codenvy

Tags: java, bitbucket, eclipse-che

I am new to eclipse che and trying it out in codenvy, now i want to connect it to my private bitbucket repository, but it keep saying fail, how to do that?

I will be glad if a full and tested tutorial as an answer, also as an tutorial for others.

Comment: what is the complete error?

Comment: just the systems states something like cannot access it

Comment: i think something like username and password is required but i just cannot find a button for bitbucket, instead get a button for github. I will be glad if a full and tested tutorial as an answer.

Comment: I was just testing this and yeap, I wasn't able to get my project from a private bitbucket repo to codenvy... tried even generating dev keys and using the ssh stuff with no luck...

Comment: I found that you can make it by manually adding a VCS private key generayed by bitbucket, then connect using the ssh.

Comment: Please add your solution as answer and accept it. It can help other shaving similar problem that search for questions with answers.